# MVC: Edit Action is not invoking the Edit view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have an Edit action. When the Action is invoked I expected the Edit view to render but it does not.  The view is Edit.cshtml.  I have a similar view Add.cshtml which works fine (Add is a button and Edit is a link inside the grid.

**The Controller method**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            var jurisdictionId = _user.Current().JurisdictionId;
            OrganizationType ot = new OrganizationType();
            ot.Id = Id;
            ot.OrganizationName = _electedOfficials.getOrgTypeName(jurisdictionId, Id);

            return View(ot);
            //return View("Edit", ot);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger?.LogCritical(new EventId(101, "CAdminOrganizationType"), e, $"Error when loading Edit Orginization Type View");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**The Edit View** (Edit.cshtml)

```
@model Platinum.Entities.OrganizationType
@{

       ViewData["Title"] = "Editing Organization Type";
}

<div class="card pd-20 pd-sm-40">
<div class="form-layout">
    <form asp-action="Edit">
        <div class="row mg-b-25">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input asp-for="Id" hidden />
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="OrganizationName" class="form-control-label">Name</label>
                    <input asp-for="OrganizationName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="OrganizationName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form-layout-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Organization Type" class="btn btn-default mg-r- 5" />
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-danger mg-r-5">Back</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

@section scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    });
</script>
}
```

**The Javascript that executes when Edit is clicked in the Index view**

```
    function Edit(id) {
        var url = '/CAdminOrganizationType/Edit/' + id

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).fail(function () {
            magalert.communicationError();
        });
    }
```

[image: The Add view works fine. Not sure why Edit is not.]

Comment: can you post your index view too pls?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, we couldn't render page without returning to ajax response.

Since the ajax will send the request to the controller action and the action returns the view as html response back to the ajax.
But you do not handle the response in ajax so that the current page will not change.

If you just want to pass the Id to Edit method and return the Edit view, I suggest you could try to use `window.location`, this will make this page redirect to the Edit view which achieve refresh the whole page.

Besides `window.location` only supports get method.I suggest you use `[HttpGet]` method to render the page, and then load the page in the success function in `ajax`.

Here is my code:

**Ajax**

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function Edit(id) {
        var url = '/Home/Edit/' + id

        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success:function(){
                window.location.href="/Home/Edit/"+id  
            },
            error:function () {
                magalert.communicationError();
            }
         });
    }
    </script>
}
```

**The Controller Method**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                var jurisdictionId = _user.Current().JurisdictionId;
                OrganizationType ot = new OrganizationType();
                ot.Id = Id;
                ot.OrganizationName = _electedOfficials.getOrgTypeName(jurisdictionId, Id);    
                return View(ot);                    
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger?.LogCritical(new EventId(101, "CAdminOrganizationType"), e, $"Error when loading Edit Orginization Type View");
                throw;
            }
            
        }
```

**Then,you can load the View**

[image]

Comment: This worked perfect!!!